# HttpClient response (text/html) to Iframe

Tags: java, iframe, portlet, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need an idea to solve this problem:

1. I have a Portlet that submit a form on external URL (outside the portal). The submit was provided with HttpClient and HttpPost.
2. The result is a html page. (obviously)

Now..

I need to put this content into an iframe (and use it after...) 
The URI that I used in httpPost, I cannot use it inside the iframe src attribute, because the page would be reloaded with loosing all previous information.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Call the following javascript method, giving the result HTML page as paramter. (Suppose the id of the iframe is "iframeId")

```
function setIFrame(result_html){
    $("#iframeId").contents().find('html').html(result_html);
}
```